# location.hash not waiting rendering on firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

I'm using this javascript event.

```
      myDatepicker.addEventListener('dateChange.mdb.datepicker', (e) => {
        var params = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
        params.set('date', Datepicker1.value.replaceAll('/', "-"));
        window.location.hash = 'graph';
        window.location.search = params.toString();
      });
```

In chrome everything is working as expected.

In firefox the event doesn't wait for the page to be rendered so it doesn't scroll to the right place. However if I press enter on the url after the event or enter the url manually, it is working as expected.

How can I force firefox to wait until the page rendering is complete?

Max

ps: What I tried following barmar comment with the same result

```
      redirect = (e) => {
        var params = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
        params.set('date', Datepicker1.value.replaceAll('/', "-"));
        window.location.hash = 'graph';
        window.location.search = params.toString();
      };
      myDatepicker.addEventListener('dateChange.mdb.datepicker', redirect);
      document.addEventListener('load', redirect);
```

ps2: It seem to be the intended comportment with the reloading of firefox not deleting some elements from the cache that other browser do.

Comment: Put the code inside the `window.load` event listener.

Comment: It is already in an event listener (I updated the post to include it), how can I have it in both event listener?